# Accessing Raw NIDAQMx data through Python with npTDMS, Or, the vicarious vista of LabView

Tags: python, labview

**Problem**

I have created a simulated system on my desktop computer consisting of a PCIe6738 providing a 1kHz dual channel signal to a simulated USB 3646 which is driven using a certain virtual instrument. These data are gathered in a local folder as a .tdms file. I am able to access the contents through the following lines of python code

```
import numpy as np
import nptdms as npt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Read in the file

tdmsFile = npt.TdmsFile.read("ITestTDMS.tdms")
all_groups = tdmsFile.groups()
```

all_groups holds the data I am seeking. See the hierarchy in the screenshot attached to this email (radarCartHope.png)

[A foray in arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPSEN.png)

I am unsure how to manipulate `all_groups` in order to access the raw nparray of data. I have attempted  `all_groups[0]["_channels"]['SimDev1/ai0']['data']` and its derivatives. May you help me learn how to access these data?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use a "native" TDMS viewer or a similar tool in order to understand how groups and channels are organized in your the TDMS file.
You can use:

- (If you have LabVIEW) the VI [TDMS File Viewer](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/tdms_file_viewer/)
- [The addon for Excel](https://www.ni.com/de-de/support/downloads/tools-network/download.tdm-excel-add-in-for-microsoft-excel.html#378046)

I never used Python to read a TDMS file. Anyway the TDMS file has this typical organization:

- Group name is the device name. It is the name of the NI acquisition board. It is defined in the NI MAX (NI Measurement and Automation software). I think in your case it is SimDev1. Differete devices (boards) corresponds to different groups.
- Every group contains some channels. The channel name should be: ai0, ai1, ai2, ecc....